# Mapping from Maven standard directory to Bazel for test resources

Tags: bazel

We have test dependency files in `src/test/resources` per the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). These test files end up in the JAR and on the classpath when test classes fetch them via, e.g. [`Resources#asCharSource`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Resources.html#asCharSource-java.net.URL-java.nio.charset.Charset-).

What is the preferred way in Bazel to depend to test files and have them appear in the classpath?

I have the following in my `src/test/resources/BUILD`:

```
filegroup(
    name = "test-deps",
    testonly = 1,
    srcs = glob(["*.txt"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

And the following in my `src/main/java/com/path/to/my/test/BUILD`:

```
java_test(
    name = "MyTest",
    srcs = ["MyTest.java"],
    resources = ["//src/test/resources:test-deps"],
    test_class = "com.path.to.my.test.MyTest",
    deps = [
        "//src/main/com/path/to/my/code",
        "//:junit_junit",
    ],    
)
```

This works, but I'm not sure if it is the best way in Bazel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is the recommended approach.  As mentioned in the [docs for resources](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/java.html#java_library.resources), Bazel understands the Maven Standard Directory Layout and will put the data files at the right classpath:

> The location of the resources inside of the jar file is determined by
>   the project structure. Bazel first looks for Maven's standard
>   directory layout, (a "src" directory followed by a "resources"
>   directory grandchild).

If you wanted to bundle the resource separately, you could create a resources-only jar and then depend on it with the [`resource_jars`](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/java.html#java_library.resource_jars) attribute.

Edit: as Ittai points out below, Bazel will not introspect resources, so you'd have to be careful not to end up with any collisions (e.g., pkg1/src/main/resources/foo and pkg2/src/main/resources/foo). Neither `resources` not `resource_jars` will check this for you, so if this is a concern, you might want to put any resources you need in a filegroup and have a genrule target or test that checks for collisions.

Comment: after reading about the resource_jars it sounds like it might be an unwise choice for *production* code, no? Since it might bring several copies of the same resource to multiple jars on production

Comment: `resources` actually won't protect you, either, added a section about this.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. What we're doing now is creating a new java_library target and adding it as a dependency