# Adding xml resource files to classpath in Bazel

Tags: java, bazel

I'm currently using Bazel on my project, and it needs to load some `.xml` files which are located in `src/resources` (you know, the standard Maven file structure). The thing is, when I build the project, this files are not imported into the classpath.

I know that `java_library` and `java_binary` have the `resources` option, but that seems to be for java classes. I tried adding it anyways like this: `resources = glob(["src/resources/**"])` but it did not work.

So, how can I add those `.xml` files to the classpath, so they are added into the compiled `.jar`?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using [filegroup](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#filegroup) as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072078/mapping-from-maven-standard-directory-to-bazel-for-test-resources/43074938#43074938) question.