# Bazel for test resources - Input path does not exist:

Tags: bazel

I am trying to use Bazel for java tests. And need to access data files under resources. My project has standard Maven structure. I am using filegroup for the resources and have it as dependency in java_test.
The issue is when i try to run the test, it fails with following error `java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/private/var/tmp/_bazel_username/2c26269e9af968f4ce3e88b22720114e/execroot/myproject/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/hadoop/com_company_hadoop_search_join_TermTest.jar!/com/company/hadoop/search/join/names.txt`
I have following in my src/test/resources/BUILD:

```
filegroup(
    name = "resources",
    testonly = 1,
    srcs = glob(["**/*.txt"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

And the following in my hadoop/BUILD:

```
java_test(
    srcs = 
        ["src/test/java/com/company/hadoop/search/join/TermTest.java"],
    resources = ["//hadoop/src/test/resources:resources"],
deps = [
        "//src/main/java/com/path/to/my/code",
        "//:junit_junit",
    ],    
)
```

I verified the test jar contents and text file does exist as expected.

Comment: please take a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072078/mapping-from-maven-standard-directory-to-bazel-for-test-resources]

Answer (score 2):

I believed your test "resources" are not *java resources* but *data* files.

Use the [data attribute](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#common.data):

```
java_test(
    srcs = [
        "src/test/java/com/company/TermTest.java",
    ],
    data = [
        "//hadoop/src/test/resources:resources",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//src/main/java/com/path/to/my/code"
    ],    
)
```